# JavaFX block MouseEvent until delayedExecutor finishes its job

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to create a simple memory match game using Java 11 and JavaFX.

I have a scenario where two cards don't match. Before the non-matching cards are flipped back I'd like to have 800 milliseconds delay, so the user can see what was the second selected card. I'm using this code and it works fine:

```
CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).execute(() -> {
    firstRevealedCard.setFaceDown();  // sets an ImageView's setImage() method
    secondRevealedCard.setFaceDown();  // sets an ImageView's setImage() method

    firstRevealedCard = null;   // sets instance variable to null
    secondRevealedCcard = null; // sets instance variable to null
});
```

All the cards in the game are in a 4 column and 2 row GridPane.

Each cell in the grid is an ImageView set to an Image.

Each card object has a Mouse (click) event attached to it:

```
// Add all cards to the deck
for ( int card_ID = 1; card_ID < unique_cards+1; card_ID++ ) {
    Card card1 = new Card( card_ID );
    card1.setOnMouseClicked( (MouseEvent event) -> { onMouseClicked(card1); });
    addCard(card1);

    Card card2 = new Card( card_ID );
    card2.setOnMouseClicked( (MouseEvent event) -> { onMouseClicked(card2); });
    addCard( card2 );
```

In the code above `card1` and `card2` are two cards having the same picture. They're matching cards.

The cards are stored in an ArrayList. After all the cards has been added to the ArrayList, the ArrayList is shuffled.

The ArrayList store Card objects and each object has its own mouse event listener attached.

THE ISSUE: When two cards don't match, the non-matching cards need to flip back and the 800 milliseconds timeout works well using the `CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor`, but I want the "mouse event" to be blocked or locked until the Executor fininshes, otherwise, let's say the user clicks an other card, but the non-matching cards didn't have the chance to flip back.

```
First card selected - Apple
Second card selected - Banana
Two non-matching cards
    Executor starts
      100 milliseconds
      100 milliseconds
      100 milliseconds
      100 milliseconds
        the user clicks another card (throws an exception)
        just because user clicked another card before executor finishes
      100 millisecond
      ...
      ...
      at 800 milliseconds
    Executor finishes, cards are flipped back

Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at memorygamefx.CardDeck.lambda$onMouseClicked$0(CardDeck.java:85)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
```

I would be grateful for any suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: According to the stack trace you posted, line 85 in file `CardDeck.java` is throwing a `NullPointerException`. [edit] your question and post that line. Better yet, post the method containing that line and indicate which is the line throwing the exception.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: I don't recommend non-application threads here. Use the `javafx.animation` package depending on your needs `Timeline` and/or `PauseTransition`, `SequentialTransition`, `ParallelTransition` and the like may do, but in general I'd create a "game manager" object that the cards tell about, when they are clicked with can then decide to handle the click as it so chooses or ignore it based on the fact that the card is currently animating or the fact that there is a animation turing some cards face down happening.

Comment: Also note that you shouldn't modify the GUI from a background thread which your code seems to be doing. Also note that if you want the application to properly shut down, you probably need to shut down that `Executor` (at least I don't know any `Executor` implementations that shut themselfs down automagically).

Comment: The `CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor` uses the [common fork join pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--), which shuts itself down automagically.  But anyway, there are better options for this work as pointed out by Fabian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use delayedExecutor for this.  If you continue to do so, wrap the delayed code you invoke in Platform.runLater, so that it runs on the JavaFX thread otherwise weird stuff might happen.

Instead use a PauseTransition such as this:

```
PauseTransiton pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(800));
Node disabledNode = scene.getRoot();
disabledNode.setDisable(true); 
pause.setOnFinished(e -> {
    disabledNode.setDisable(false);
    // delayed code that you would like to run.
});
pause.play();
```

The example disables the entire scene when the pause is executing.

A binding can also be used instead, but manually setting and unsetting the disable property is probably better:

```
scene.getRoot().disableProperty().bind(
    Bindings.equal(pause.statusProperty(), Animation.Status.RUNNING)
);
```

Disabling the scene will, by default, grey it out to give feedback that it is disabled.  If you don't want that, you could instead add or remove a [mouse event filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/filters.htm) (please read attached link to understand this if you don't know what it is) on a scene or a hierarchy or nodes to prevent input that you don't want the app to process during the pause.

Another thing you could do to disable mouse input, is to set the root node to [`mouseTransparent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setMouseTransparent(boolean)) while the pause is running, that way mouse input will be ignored.  That would be similar to defining your own filters to ignore mouse events, but much easier to implement.

Some advantage of a PauseTransition are:

1. Everything runs on the JavaFX thread, so you don't need to deal with multi-threading issues.
2. It has a rich API so it is quite flexible.
3. It is reusable.

Comment: Thank you so much. I used the first example that you posted. I didn't notice any graying out on the scene. Everything works fine.